# Maximum Likelyhood ratio Decision in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I'm facing this problem: I've two sets of random data (array of doubles `data1` and `data2`), and I also have another random data point (single double value `dataI`).

How can I estimate if `dataI` belongs better to the `data1` or `data2` set?

Comment: What do you mean by _belongs better_? The likelihood that `dataI` is generated by the same process that generated `data1` or `data2`?

Comment: yes. i want do do this extimation througt the maximum likelyhood ratio.

Comment: Do you have models describing your data? If not, a likelihood ratio test is not going to work. 

Since you are comparing a scalar to two data vectors, I'd personally just compute a some distance metric for `dataI` to `data1` and `data2`, respectively, and select the data set for which said metric is the smallest. I do not feel there is enough information (a single data point is not all that informative) to warrant a different approach.

Comment: If I could have an array of array of data generated from process one and another array of array generated from process two and another array of data how could i determine the likelihood that this data is generated from process one or two?

Comment: I.e. 

    `DataSetOne=[ array_of_data_extrated_from_process_one_at_time_1;
array_of_data_extrated_from_process_one_at_time_2;
...];`

   `DataSetTwo=[ array_of_data_extrated_from_process_two_at_time_1;
array_of_data_extrated_from_process_two_at_time_2;
...];`

   `DataToTest=[array];`

Now i have to determine if DataToTest is generated from process one or process two. Any help @N.Wouda?

Comment: There are many ways, but a non-parametric approach would be a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, [like so](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get anywhere with this problem, you have to make some assumption about the process which generated the two data sets. The simplest is that each data set is drawn from a Gaussian distribution, with different mean and variance for each distribution. Depending on what you know about the problem, it is entirely reasonable to make other assumptions. If you say more about the problem, we can help with that.

The class (i.e. which group) probability `p(c_i|x)` is just `p(x|c_i) p(c_i)/(p(x|c_1) p(c_1) + p(x|c_2) p(c_2))`. Under the Gaussian assumption, `p(x|c_i)` is just `G(x;mu_i, sigma_i)` where `G` is the Gaussian density function. You can estimate the mean and variance of each group as the sample mean and sample variance. The `p(c_i)` are the class priors, i.e. the proportion of data in each class.

After computing `p(c_i|x)` for each class (where i = 1 or i = 2), you can decide that `x` comes from the class which has greatest `p(c_i|x)`. This is essentially assuming equal loss or cost for misclassification of either class. If there are different misclassification costs, you can apply a cost matrix and make the assignment with least expected cost. I can explain that if you are interested.

The general topic of "mixture modeling" is relevant here.

Comment: Why would you explicitly suggest a parametric approach when so little is known about the underlying process? Not saying it's wrong, but I would definitely enjoy you expanding on the topic a bit more.

Comment: OP can plug in any kind of estimate for `p(x|c)`. Kernel density, histogram, parametric model, etc. A Gaussian density is just the simplest thing that might work.

Comment: I would refrain from assuming normality (or any other parameterised approach) like that, unless more is known about the generating process. An empirical estimation of the distribution would definitely work, but that is essentially the same approach as a two-sided Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (or any other standard non-parametric approach to comparing two samples for their underlying distribution).

Comment: @RobertDodier In oreder to give you additional information about the problem, I have a collection of images and in each image is located an object. 

Supposing that I know the exact postion of this object in a set of images i would like to estimate the position of the object in new coming images giving the problem a statistic approach.

So, I have a class of pixels generated by the background process, and a second class of pixels generated by the object process. And, when new image comes I would like to make a pixel by pixel decision to say if the pixel is more likely background or object.

Comment: Well, it seems like a pixel by pixel decision could work only if the pixel values in the background are more or less the same over the entire image and also the pixel values of the object are also more or less the same. If that's the case then it seems like it could work. Otherwise, my advice is to construct a generative model of pixel values given object shape and location, and apply Bayes theorem to infer object shape and location from pixel values. (That is a nontrivial computation, of course.) I believe that approach is covered in texts on machine vision.